# Pl/Sql How to change collection element's without using loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to change a collection's elements indexes without using any loop. How can i do that?

```
declare
   type NumberList is table of pls_integer;
   nlist NumberList := NumberList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
   n_first pls_integer := 1;
   n_last pls_integer := 10;
```

I want to make `nlist` like `(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can order desc the elements in a select and collect the result into a new list

```
  select * bulk collect into nlist2 from (
    select column_value from table(nlist) order by 1 desc
  );
```

your nested table should be declared as a global type

```
CREATE or replace TYPE NumberList  IS TABLE OF pls_integer;
```

than you can use it

```
declare
   nlist NumberList := NumberList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
   n_first pls_integer := 1;
   n_last pls_integer := 10;
   nlist2 NumberList 
begin
  select * bulk collect into nlist2 from (
    select column_value from table(nlist) order by 1 desc
  );


end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nested tables are not ordered, so actually your request does not make much sense.

If you like to get the elements in a certain order then use

```
select column_value from table(nlist) order by 1 desc
```

Note, you can store such arrays in tables but when you select those elements again then the order of elements can be arbitrary, see [Nested Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS99929):

> In the database, a nested table is a column type that stores an
>   unspecified number of rows in no particular order.
>
> When you retrieve a nested table value from the database into a PL/SQL
>   nested table variable, PL/SQL gives the rows consecutive indexes,
>   starting at 1. Using these indexes, you can access the individual rows
>   of the nested table variable. The syntax is variable_name(index). The
>   indexes and row order of a nested table might not remain stable as you
>   store and retrieve the nested table from the database.

Comment: "PL/SQL tables are not ordered" - I suppose you mean *nested* tables? (There is no such thing as a "PL/SQL table".) If so, then that statement is true in theory, but not in practice. Nested tables are indexed, and the indexes are visible (they can be accessed in code), which makes nested tables ordered. Nested tables in SQL are different, members can't be accessed by index, but even there the "order" seems to be preserved - if you select from a nested table the elements will be generated in index order, although this doesn't seem to be stated in the documentation.

Comment: @mathguy, you are right, it must be **nested table** - however see [Associative Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#GUID-8060F01F-B53B-48D4-9239-7EA8461C2170): *An associative array (formerly called **PL/SQL table** or index-by table) is a set of key-value pairs.*

Comment: Oh! I knew they were called (and still are sometimes) "index-by tables"; I didn't know they also used to be called "PL/SQL tables"! Learning something new every day. Of course, though, the OP wasn't asking about these.